# Taking the Fourier Transform of a specific function.

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have this function:

$$f(x) = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}} \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{p^2}\right)$$

Now, this function can be said to be an infinite degree polynomial with zeros on each of the primes and their negatives and nowhere else.

Properties of $f(x)$ that I'm aware of:

- $f(x)$ is an even function.
- The zeroes of $f(x)$ are the set of prime numbers union the set of their negatives.
- $f(x)$ is continuous.
- $-\infty < f(x) < \infty \quad {\small \text{This stems from the previous two properties.}}$

Now, what I have so far is the following:

$$
\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2\pi i x\xi}\left(\prod_{p\text{ is prime}} \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{p^2}\right)\right)\ dx
$$

I can't manage to get any further.

Is there a way to get a closed form for the Fourier transform of this function?

---

### Additional information:

$f(x)$ is known to have at least one non-zero point.

$$f(1) = \zeta(2)^{-1} = \frac{6}{\pi^2} \approx 0.6079$$

Comment: That's not a function define for any $x$. What is $f(0)$?

Comment: Ugh, my mistake. It's technically only defined on the primes and it's undefined on everything else. I'm going to be correcting the question, there's a missing factor.

Comment: The general form would be something like $\prod_p \left(1-\frac{x^2}{p^2}\right)$.

Comment: That function works and still has the same properties that I outlined, I believe. I'll use that instead in the question rather than the mess I actually have (which is probably also still wrong).

Comment: Hmm. Do you know if this function is in $L^1$ or $L^2$?

Comment: I'm not sure how you ensure that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't ensure that it's limit is $0$ as it approaches $\infty$. What I do ensure is that it will never be $\infty$. The reason for this is that for any zero-point, there is another zero-point on either side of it. If it were to be $\infty$ or undefined at any point in between, it would cease to be continuous.

Comment: I guess I forgot to quote you and now it's too late to edit the post, @ThomasAndrews . There was some discussion in chat that led to the discovery of a non-zero point of the function. I'll be adding that to the question's text sometime today.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: lmfdb.org